# Can we encrypt the BIRT Connection Profile without Eclipse IDE?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, encryption, jdbc, birt

I am using encrypted connection profile to store the data source information for my BIRT reports.When I want to change the password for the DB I use following procedure.

1. Delete the current connection profile(encrypted file) and profile from Data Source Explorer in Eclipse IDE
2. Create new connection profile(with same name as earlier) from Data Source Explorer in Eclipse IDE with new information.
3. Export encrypted connection profile with same name as initial file.

Is there a way to do this without using eclipse IDE,  or is there a another way to change passwords in the encrypted connection profiles easily ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way your are doingt it now is the best.

If you look at the BIRT source code, you'll seet hat BIRT uses some Java security classes to generate the secret key. Probably it IS possible to generate an encrypted connection profile store with another program, but this would have to be written in Java and duplicate some of the BIRT source code.

It would be great if the BIRT IDE allowed us to modify a connection's password in an encrypted profile store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are on Windows you can use the Application: [BIRT Default Encrypted Connection Profile Editor](https://github.com/packone/birt-deconp-editor).

I initially had the same question and solved it for my purpose.
No Eclipse or Java required to change the default encrypted Connection Profile File.
I put everything of my research in the git Repository.
If the Application does not meet your needs you can try implementing something based on the informations provided.